# Steps doesn't generate in Extent Report in specflow

Tags: specflow, extentreports, selenium-extent-report

I am generating an extent report in specflow, I have written the code and my test execute successfully and report generating but it displays only the feature name no steps name displayed in the report.
Please suggest me what mistake I am doing in the code.
I am attaching a screenshot of my generated report, When I go to report dashboard it displays the number of steps there.

```
using AventStack.ExtentReports;
using AventStack.ExtentReports.Reporter;
using AventStack.ExtentReports.Reporter.Configuration;
using NUnit.Framework;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using TechTalk.SpecFlow;

namespace Extent_Report
{
    [Binding]
    [TestFixture]
    class Hooks
    {
        public static ExtentReports extent;
        public static ExtentHtmlReporter htmlReporter;
        public static ExtentTest test;

        //  public static object Theme { get; private set; }

        static Hooks()
        {
            if (extent == null)
            {
                BasicSetUp();
            }

        }

        [BeforeScenario]
        public static void Setup()
        {
            BasePage.Intitialize();
            BasePage.Navigate();
            test = extent.CreateTest(ScenarioContext.Current.ScenarioInfo.Title);
        }

        [AfterScenario]
        public void TearDown()
        {
            if (ScenarioContext.Current.TestError != null)
            {
                var error = ScenarioContext.Current.TestError;
                var errormessage = "<pre>" + error.Message + "</pre>";

                extent.AddTestRunnerLogs(errormessage);
                test.Log(Status.Error, errormessage);
                test.Fail(errormessage);

            }
            BasePage.Quit();
        }

        [OneTimeSetUp]
        public static void BasicSetUp()
        {
            string pth = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetCallingAssembly().CodeBase;
            // string pth = System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
            string actualPath = pth.Substring(0, pth.LastIndexOf("bin"));
            string projectPath = new Uri(actualPath).LocalPath;
            Console.WriteLine(" -----------Project Path--------------------------------------");
            Console.WriteLine(projectPath);
            string reportPath = projectPath + "Reports\\TestExecutionRunReport.html";
            // Console.WriteLine("Report Path is " + reportPath);


            htmlReporter = new ExtentHtmlReporter(reportPath);
            htmlReporter.Configuration().Theme = Theme.Dark;


            htmlReporter.Configuration().DocumentTitle = "SpecFlow Test Resport Document";

            htmlReporter.Configuration().ReportName = "Feature Run Results";

            extent = new ExtentReports();

            extent.AttachReporter(htmlReporter);
            //extent.LoadConfig(projectPath + "Extent-Config.xml");

        }


        [AfterFeature()]
        public static void EndReport()
        {
            extent.Flush();

        }

    }
}
```

Reference:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to use hook [After step] or [Before step] and add below content to it

test = test.info(ScenarioStepContext.Current.StepInfo.Text);

you can also manipulate and provide more information in it if required.